# Code Analysis Errors Only on Build Server

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, code-analysis

I'm trying to figure out why code analysis would run and detect errors on our build server, but I don't see the same errors when building locally. Here is one example of code that's failing (because of our STBi acronym):

```
string message = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
    "Unit STBi [{0}] blah... ",
    unitStbiParameter.Stbi);
```

The build fails on our TFS build server with errors like this:

> CA2204 : Microsoft.Naming :
>   Correct the spelling of the unrecognized token 'STBi' in the literal
>   '"Unit STBi ["'.

The problem is that I don't know why I'm not seeing these CA errors when I build the solution on my laptop. This is in the project's properties:

[image]

And the build definition has this:

[image]

Why would errors show from a build on the build machine but not my laptop? It's almost like the build server is using a different CA rule set. Is that possible?

Side note: I tried adding STBi to the CustomDictionary.xml (below), but that still didn't help. But that's a separate issue.

```
<!-- This is here because it's a workaround for a bug: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/521030/ -->
<DiscreteExceptions>
  <Term>STBi</Term>
</DiscreteExceptions>
```

Comment: Did you try opening the rule-set on your laptop and checking the setting for "CA2204"? Also, is it possible you have a custom dictionary on your laptop which allows it? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514188.aspx

Comment: The rule set on my laptop has CA2204 enabled. I do have a custom dictionary which allows it, but shouldn't that same custom dictionary be used when TFS builds?

Comment: I think it should... If it's part of the solution?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to specify the `CodeAnalysisCulture` MSBuild property in your project(s) (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2007/08/12/new-for-visual-studio-2008-spelling-rules.aspx for an example).  Without this set, spelling rules will use the Windows UI culture information for the account under which the analysis is running, which is presumably different for your account and the build account.

Answer (score 1):

Are you building debug locally and release on the Build Server? If so, check that the CA settings are the same for debug and release, and that your dictionary is checked in and the same on the build server.

My team use CA enabled on debug builds and CA is *disabled* on the build server. The code analysis check-in policy ensures that CA has been run on all code in source control, so is there any point in slowing down your server builds with repeated code analysis passes?

Comment: I'm building debug locally and debug and release on the build server. But it's failing as debug on the build server, so it's not a debug/release difference.

Comment: Jason can you provide anymore info about how you set-up your code analysis check-in policy? I'm trying to set up code analysis similarly for my team and running into problems.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't remember much - this was 5 years ago, and things are different where i now work There was a CA policy that you simply enabled, and check-ins were rejected if CA hadn't been run on the source. I don't recall having to do anything clever to get it working.